# Why do I get "DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop" when using asyncio.get_event_loop?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Why do I get "DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop" on below code?

```
import sys

from LXPPacket import LXPPacket
import asyncio

SERVER_URL = "172.16.255.120"
# SERVER_URL = "127.0.0.1"
SERVER_PORT = 8000


async def tcp_echo_client(loop):
    while True:
        try:
            address = int(input("Register Address: "))
            reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(SERVER_URL, SERVER_PORT,
                                                           loop=loop)
            print("Connected to server")
            lxpPacket = LXPPacket()
            packet = lxpPacket.prepare_packet_for_read(address, 1)
            writer.write(packet)
            await writer.drain()
            # await asyncio.sleep(1)
            packet = await reader.read(1000)
            print('Received: ', packet)
            result = lxpPacket.parse_packet(packet)
            if not lxpPacket.packet_error:
                print(result)
            print('Close the socket')
            writer.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception ", e)
            print(sys.gettrace())

if __name__ =="__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(tcp_echo_client(loop))
    loop.close()
```

```
Error - LXPReadTester.py:35: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

Answer (score 1):

replace the last 4 lines with the following:

```py
async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    await tcp_echo_client(loop)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

calling `asyncio.run` is the proper way to start (and close) an asyncio eventloop.

the problem is in calling `asyncio.get_event_loop()`, which is going to raise an error in the future when called without a running eventloop, you should instead replace it with `asycio.new_event_loop()`, or use `asyncio.run()` instead and let asyncio handle the creation and termination of the loop.

Comment: 'Register Address: 20
Exception  BaseEventLoop.create_connection() got an unexpected keyword argument 'loop'
None
Register Address:'

Comment: @DionVandenBerg you should remove the `loop` from everywhere in your code.

Comment: @DionVandenBerg or update python to some newer version

Answer (score 0):

#### I don't think you should pass in the `loop` to `tcp_echo_client`

It is sufficient to pass it only to `asyncio.open_connection`.

You can simplify your final section to this:

```
if __name__ =="__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(tcp_echo_client())
    loop.close()
```

Comment: Now get -  'Exception  BaseEventLoop.create_connection() got an unexpected keyword argument 'loop''